# Haskell Platform Installation

Tags: haskell, installation

I tried to install Haskell Platform from the official website and they asked me to configure Chocolatey on my computer and then to run choco install haskell-dev refreshenv, so I did it and installed:

- ghc v8.10.1
- chocolatey-core.extension v1.3.5.1
- haskell-dev v0.0.1
- msys2 v20190524.0.0.20191030
- cabal v3.2.0.0

and now i have no idea how to get started with the Haskell and whether I've installed everything I needed, could somebody help me?

Comment: just try running `ghci` in a shell to check.

Comment: There is a new section in cabal docs for getting started that could be useful: http://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

This looks like pretty much everything you need. It looks like you’re struggling a bit to understand what everything is for, so I’ll explain the purpose of each component:

- `ghc` is the Glasgow Haskell Compiler a.k.a. GHC, which compiles your code to an executable. Also included in this package is `ghci`, the GHC interpreter a.k.a. GHCi, which you can use to interactively enter and execute code.
- `haskell-dev` [appears](https://chocolatey.org/packages/haskell-dev) to be an auxiliary package to get `msys2` properly set up.
- `msys2` is [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), which provides an environment allowing access to Unix-like tools. You won’t need it for simple stuff, but it can be invaluable when trying to build some Haskell packages.
- `cabal` is the Haskell package manager. (Well, one Haskell package manager: the alternative is Stack, which is compatible with Cabal.) You’ll be using this to develop, build and install Haskell packages.

As for ‘how to get started with Haskell’, this isn’t really the place to ask (maybe try [Reddit /r/haskell](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/)), but off the top of my head I can think of http://learnyouahaskell.com/ and https://haskellbook.com/ as well-known resources for learning the basics. If you already know the basics and want to start learning more advanced features, try [What I Wish I Knew When Learning Haskell](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/).